# "Execution Timeout Expired" messages in Azure Storage Queue - database records not being pushed to search index for last several days

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-service-fabric

All below information may not be necessary for diagnosis/assistance but providing it all for full context:

Every 24 hours a series of Azure SQL Server (2016) stored procedures in-tandem with microservices code housed in Azure Service Fabric pushes our latest database records to our ElasticSearch index. I noted today that the ElasticSearch index has not received any new records over the last 6 days.

I examined our Index Queue inside Azure Storage Explorer to discover that all these records from the last 6 days are stuck in the queue. This is the first time this has happened since this application was put into production several months ago.

There are two different error messages in the associated poison queue, neither of which am I able to decipher.  The most common-occurring error between the two is:

> Exception":"OPERATION=Archive;EXCEPTION=Execution Timeout Expired.
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.;PAYLOAD=12241;
>
> STACKTRACE=
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- 
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.d__17.MoveNext()\r\n--- 
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.d__13.MoveNext()\r\n
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
>   at CANTREL.SOURCES.PERSISTENCE.REPOSITORIES.SOURCESREPOSITORY.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
>   at CANTREL.SERVICES.SOURCES.ARCHIVER.SOURCEARCHIVER.d__7.MoveNext()","Id":"455983d9-c68b-4a5d-84ff-5e9be4547af5","Content":null}

The two projects that begin with CANTREL are the only items in this message that I recognize/understand - I have access to these ASP.NET solutions, but I can't imagine these are the root of the issue as the code in these projects has remained untouched since publishing inception.

Here is the flow of the application:

1. Records get written to database holding table each night.
2. SQL Server Trigger replicates records to a different table, and marks each record with a status of 501 (ready for sync).
3. Holding table is truncated.
4. A series of 3 stored procedures run to determine which records needs to be pushed to the ElasticSearch index, as well as delete unneeded records.
5. Indexer microservice on Azure checks the table every 12 hours for new 501's, and puts them into the aforementioned queue to be pushed to the ElasticSearch Index.
6. The queue pushes the records to the index, and the indexer microservice changes the status of the records in the database table to 1 (Indexed).

Somewhere within steps 5 and 6 is where the issue is arising. The queue is currently at 200k records and that count is rising by the minute. I need assistance figuring out how to get these items out of this queue and into the index.

Thus far I've run a query on the database to check for `blocking processes`.  There are none.  I don't know what else could be causing the issue. Other database functions such as `INSERTS`, `DELETES`, and `SELECTS` can all be performed without issue.

2 days before this started happening, I scaled up this database in Azure to a higher tier, which was reported as successful.  I have scaled up and down many times w/o issue.  Also, I restarted our ElasticSearch service several times on Thursday, but this was several days *after* the problem began. Nonethelesss, I felt it worth mentioning these items as these are the only outstanding changes made to **anything** related to this application since or around the time this started happening.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT #1 - 2018-09-03:**  I've added a line of code to the `DBContext` class to increase database connection timeout to 300 seconds.  This seems to put a temporary "band-aid" on the situation as the timeout errors are no longer appearing and the queue is starting to clear (although very slowly).  But as 30 seconds timeout has been our setting for many months w/o issue, this is only a temporary solution, and I still need to do a root cause analysis.

Comment: If the messages are going in the queue, that means step 5 is working I think. How are the messages dequeued from the queue (in step 6)? Have you checked for the errors in that process?

Comment: The indexer microservice in Azure Service Fabric accomplishes that, but I honestly don't know much more than that.  I inherited this with no knowledge transfer.  Trying to figure out what the heck is going on here. Is there any kind of error log in Service Fabric that you're aware of?  I think unfortunately what I've posted here is the only error available to me.

Comment: @Stpete111 Did your issue involve scaling of the SQL server by any chance ?

Comment: @Etienne the issue ended up lying within the microservices.  We upgraded our microservices from .NET 4.6 to .NET core 3, and the issues have disappeared.